# Tableview Reload cell issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Okay, so I finally figured out how to expand and collapse a cell. Now I come across this strange bug. I have a button, when click it reloads the data in the row and scrolls to the top. It makes a weird animation, here is a [Video](https://youtu.be/WCfpIWFwrEo) for a better visual. Would appreciate the help.

So I'm using a delegate, that allows me to check which cell button is being click. Then reloading the cell and scrolling to the top. This how my code looks

```
extension MainTableVC: ItemCellDelegate {
    func detailButtonDidTap(cell: ItemCell) {
        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

        let item = categories[indexPath.section].items[indexPath.row]

        item.isDescriptionTextTruncated = !item.isDescriptionTextTruncated!

        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the relevant code, otherwise we are just guessing

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks

Comment: didn't get you what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @iOSGeek The weird animation, when the weird animation is happening. When it looks like the cell glitches.

Comment: Check If this helps you -> https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8/issues/17#issuecomment-103548808

Comment: "so I finally figured out how to expand and collapse a cell" I don't think you did. If you were doing this correctly, I would expect to see a call to `tableView.performBatchUpdates`, and I don't see one.

Comment: @matt can you provide sample code. I followed this [https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells] they don't use perform batch updates they use begin and end updates. Would appreciate a code sample.

Comment: Well I followed (and wrote) this: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/67ad3ad18f465910ffd051762c3f467059d1d0d1/bk2ch08p451dynamicTableContent2/AccordionCell/ViewController.swift